# script for SVG works, but not as call back

Tags: jquery, css, svg

I am working on an html page with an inline svg. The svg has a class of 'hidden' and a first child of g with a class of 'frametoMove'

I am trying to change the class with Jquery, to a class called 'blackframe'. That class has a css animation that rotates the first child g element by 20 degrees.

I can get this to work using the .attr() function, but it only works when it follows the function that hides the whole svg code (hence giving it the class 'hidden'

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            $('.hideme').each(function(i) {
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
                if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                    $(this).animate({
                            'opacity': '1'
                        }, 2000);
                        //works this way, but adds attr to all g:first-child elements at the same time
                            $('.hideme').children('g:first-child').attr("class", "frametoMove blackframe");

                };
            });
        });
        });    
$(document).ready(function() {
        /* Every time the window is scrolled ... */
        $(window).scroll(function() {
            /* Check the location of each desired element */
            $('.hideme').each(function(i) {
                var bottom_of_object = $(this).offset().top + $(this).outerHeight();
                var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();
                /* If the object is completely visible in the window, fade it it */
                if (bottom_of_window > bottom_of_object) {
                    $(this).animate({
                            'opacity': '1'
                        }, 2000),
//doesn’t work as callback

                        function() {
                            $('.hideme').children('g:first-child').attr("class", "frametoMove blackframe");
                        };
                };
            });
        });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When setting the `class` you are to doing it to the first child of all `hideme` elements.  Change code to

```
 $(this)
   .children('g:first-child')
   .attr("class", "frametoMove blackframe");
```

The callback doesn't work because of an early closing parenthesis.  Change to

```
$(this).animate(
   {'opacity': '1'}, 
   2000,
   function() {
     $(this)
     .children('g:first-child')
     .attr("class", "frametoMove blackframe");
   });
```

Comment: Thank so much. I would like to accept this as an answer, and vote it up. But it appears I don't have enough of a reputation. The code you sent worked really well.